# Make an angular component styled like a button (Angular Material)

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular-material, saas

When I wrap a button inside custom button components, the spacing between buttons disappears. Example.

[image]

How do I "trick" the browser into thinking that my wrapping components are normal buttons (by a saas inheritance mechanism or something like that)?

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button [disabled]="disabled">
  {{ label }} <mat-icon>navigate_next</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you give a working example or your code?

Comment: `<button type="button" mat-raised-button [disabled]="disabled">
  {{ label }}
  <mat-icon>navigate_next</mat-icon>
</button>`
The .ts is just for inputs

Comment: `<custom-button (click)="clicked()"></custom-button>
    <custom-button-two (click)="clicked()"></custom-button-two>`
would be a usage example

Comment: "Working example" means something on stackblitz, plunkr, jsfiddle, ...

where `custom-button` is defined? how?

Comment: Material styles are based on classes. Check what class is used by mat-raised-button in DevTools and try to add it manually to host element of custom-button, BUT I'm afraid it won't work as you want. You could poke around with styles from here. BTW I've had numerous small problems with wrapping buttons in custom components but I wish you luck, maybe your use case is okay.

Comment: You cannot 'trick' the browser into 'thinking' that `custom-button` is a `button`. You can only apply the same spacing to both using style.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `HostBinding` to style the component itself (not the children)